# How to make a phone call from react native without opening phone dialer or asking for selection of a call app

Tags: react-native

I am trying to call from my app. But it is opening the phone dialer.

Linking.openURL(`tel:${phoneNumber}`);

Linking.openURL(`tel:${phoneNumber}`);

Expected direct call but opening the phone dialer.

Comment: Hi, did you found any solution for this? Is also has to call directly from React Native App without opening Dialer.